# How to Reverse 'ScrollY' Effect upon Scrolling Up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make the line extends as someone scrolls down, and shrink as someone scrolls up. I am not sure what exactly missing for the JavaScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/nqu2L4mc/

JavaScript

```
// Timeline Begins
 
     "use strict";

function qs(selector, all = false) {
  return all ? document.querySelectorAll(selector) : document.querySelector(selector);
}

const sections = qs('.timeline_section', true);
const timeline = qs('.timeline');
const line = qs('.timeline_line');
line.style.bottom = `calc(100%)`;
let prevScrollY = window.scrollY;
let up, down;
let full = false;
let set = 0;
const targetY = window.innerHeight * .8;

function scrollHandler(e) {
  const {
    scrollY
  } = window;
  up = scrollY < prevScrollY;
  down = !up;
  const timelineRect = timeline.getBoundingClientRect();
  const lineRect = line.getBoundingClientRect(); // const lineHeight = lineRect.bottom - lineRect.top;

  const dist = targetY - timelineRect.top;
  console.log(dist);

  if (down && !full) {
    set = Math.max(set, dist);
    line.style.bottom = `calc(100% - ${set}px)`;
  }

  if (dist > timeline.offsetHeight + 50 && !full) {
    full = true;
    line.style.bottom = `-50px`;
  }

  sections.forEach(item => {
    // console.log(item);
    const rect = item.getBoundingClientRect(); //     console.log(rect);

    if (rect.top + item.offsetHeight / 5 < targetY) {
      item.classList.add('show-me');
    }
  }); // console.log(up, down);

  prevScrollY = window.scrollY;
}

scrollHandler();
line.style.display = 'block';
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);

// Timeline Ends
```

It would be great if someone can edit the code directly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see what you do for `down` yet what should be done with `up`?

Comment: I want to reverse the effect. With up, I want the line to shrink and text to disappear from the sides.